# Use stored procedures in Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, stored-procedures

I try to insert data into a SQL Server by calling a stored procedure but I am getting an error.

> Procedure or function 'USP_InsertNguoiDung' expects parameter '@idND', which was not supplied.

My stored procedure in SQL Server

```
create proc USP_InsertNguoiDung
    @idND nvarchar(20),
    @tenND nvarchar(100),
    @matkhauND nvarchar(100),
    @phanquyenND nvarchar(100)
as
begin
    insert into nguoidung values(@idND, @tenND, @matkhauND, @phanquyenND)
end
```

exec USP_InsertNguoiDung 'Me', N'Mẹ', '123','NguoiDung'

My code calling stored procedure

```
 'Dim con As SqlConnection = _db.Getcon()
    'con.Open()
    'Cmd = New SqlCommand("USP_InsertPeople", con)
    'Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    'Cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@id", ndDTO.NguoiDungID))
    'Cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@hoten", ndDTO.Hoten))
    'Cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@matkhau", ndDTO.Matkhau))
    'Cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@phanquyen", ndDTO.PhanQuyen))
    'Cmd.ExecuteReader()
    'con.Close()
```

Comment: Can you include the actual vb code that calls the stored procedure as, what you have included in your question, looks like a set of comments.  It calls the wrong stored procedure, for example...

Answer (score 0):

You misspelt your parameters and sproc name:

```
Dim con As SqlConnection = _db.Getcon()
con.Open()
Cmd = New SqlCommand("USP_InsertNguoiDung", con)
Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
Cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@idND", ndDTO.NguoiDungID))
Cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@tenND", ndDTO.Hoten))
Cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@matkhauND", ndDTO.Matkhau))
Cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@phanquyenND", ndDTO.PhanQuyen))
Cmd.ExecuteReader()
con.Close()
```

Comment: @MremTy: **no**, you **didn't** spell your parameters correctly in your VB.NET code. Check again. You have `@idND` as the first parameter for your stored procedure, but in your VB.NET code, you use `@id` - that's **NOT** correct - it has to be `@idND` ...